# What could cause a delay on jQuery click event adding a class to different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I'm having an issue where I click a cart icon to make a sidecart visible.

Here's some pseudo:

```
Click cart Icon
Add class 'visible' to side cart and overlay
Click on overlay
Remove class visible from side cart and overlay
```

When I click cart Icon, there appears to be a slight delay before it adds the class on the side cart and overlay. When I click on overlay to remove classes, it happens instantly.

Here's actual code

```
    var $cartToggle = $('.cart-toggle-link');
    var $sideCart = $('.side-cart');
    var $cartOverlay = $('.cart-overlay');

    // Side Cart
    $cartToggle.click(function(e) {
        /* Act on the event */
        e.preventDefault();
        $sideCart.addClass('visible');
        $cartOverlay.addClass('visible');
    });

    $cartOverlay.click(function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */
        $(this).removeClass('visible');
        $sideCart.removeClass('visible');
    });
```

Comment: Where's the HTML? Can you post all the code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Could be some css transitions at play here. Create a [mcve]

Comment: Will definitely need to see the CSS Classes if possible.

Comment: You could stick a console.log() at the end of each handler to see how fast it logs.  addClass and removeClass() are not async operations so if the console log happens before you see your effect, then you'd know it was either something with css transitions or simply your browser waiting to get a chance to redraw/reflow.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar I tried with a console.log() both before and after the addClass, and each time it fired at the same time as the addClass. I had already removed transitions etc. I'll work on a minimal, complete and verifiable example.